# Can't get mysqldump to connect to local mysql instance (error 2003 / 10061)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I've got mysql 5.1 on a windows xp machine. It's listening on port 3308. I'm trying to use mysqldump:

```
> mysqldump -u root -pmypassword dbname > out.sql
```

Getting an error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect
```

Not sure what the problem is, looking at --help dumps variables and shows port=3308 as I set in the mysql installation (instead of default 3306). I don't think there's anything different with my installation. I also tried explicitly setting the port # on the command line but still same error.

Thanks

Comment: simple test: try `telnet 127.0.0.1 3308`. Does it respond with a version number?

Comment: Have you tried `> mysqldump -u root -pmypassword -P 3308 dbname > out.sql` ?

Comment: Run `mysqladmin -u root -pmypassword variables` and check that `skip-networking` is `FALSE`.

Comment: using the -P version worked (I was using --port). Thank you all.

Comment: @ypercube post this as an answer so that it can be accepted and easier to see in future ;)

Answer (score 10):

To connect through a port (and not the default 3306), use:

```
mysqldump -u root -pmypassword -P 3308 dbname > out.sql
```

Besides that, a simple test to see if MySQL responds at port 3308 is to try telneting:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3308
```

If MySQL is listening on port 3308, it'll respond with an error and the version running.

Comment: For a very large sql file this may help you `mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF`

Answer (score 1):

Go to  run type services.msc

then
locate mysql service and start it .this solved

Comment: Yes. Its startup type is Automatic but it wasn't running.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mysql-Client is 5.5.16 please upgrade it to 5.6.10, this process worked for me if your mysql server is 5.6.10.