# Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server while taking dump from RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, export

I am trying to export database from AWS RDS to my localhost, mysql dump command is like:

```
`mysqldump -h xxxxx(my RDS account)  -u xxx(my username)  -p remote_db > dump.sql`,
```

then my terminal would ask me to enter the password, after entering passsword, it kept showing Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server, what may cause this problem? I have checked this

[Can't get mysqldump to connect to local mysql instance (error 2003 / 10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426856/cant-get-mysqldump-to-connect-to-local-mysql-instance-error-2003-10061)

and try to use this solution to fix it, but same thing happens everytime, what can i do?

Comment: Can you please make it more clear. Your dump process starts and then while the dump is in progress, when you are trying to do some operations, you are getting error? OR Is it like, the dump process itself is returning the error?

Comment: Sorry about this problem, the dump process returns the error

Comment: Are you trying to take dump from an EC2 Instance? Or from a system outside your AWS?

Comment: I am trying to use hot backup to backup my database in RDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a best practice that your database should be always private so most probably your database would be in private subnet(Not accessible from internet), If RDS is accessible from the internet so check your Security Group, NACL & Route Table configuration.

Feel free to comment if you face same issue the after above checklist.